# My modal pup up worked for years and then just one of them stopped working. I cannot seem to fix it

Tags: bootstrap-modal

One of my modal pop up windows is no longer working, and I cannot figure out why. It worked for years and just stopped recently. When I copy code from another modal pop-up and change it from modal2 to modal3, it still doesn't work.

Code below, Portfolio Item 1 works, Portfolio Item 2 does not. Page is up at https://sara-mayman.com/index-test.html.

Help! Thank you in advance!

```
                    <!-- Portfolio Item 1-->
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-5">
                        <div class="portfolio-item mx-auto" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolioModal2">
                            <div class="portfolio-item-caption d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100 w-100">
                                <div class="portfolio-item-caption-content text-center text-white"></div>
                            </div>
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="/images/card3bg.png" alt="" />
                            <div class="centered">Work</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- Portfolio Item 2-->
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-5">
                        <div class="portfolio-item mx-auto" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolioModal3">
                            <div class="portfolio-item-caption d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100 w-100">
                                <div class="portfolio-item-caption-content text-center text-white"></div>
                            </div>
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="/images/card4bg.png" alt="" />
                            <div class="centered">Video Demos</div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
```

WHen I copied all working code for modal2 and changed it to modal3 in hopes of making the pop up work, it did not fix the problem.